# How to open files (music, videos) from FTP directly from Explorer ( Windows Vista)

Tags: windows-vista, debian, windows-explorer, ftp, vsftpd

I have two computers. On the first I have Debian and on the second I have Windows Vista.
I've set up vsftpd in Debian and connected to it from Vista. I'm browsing the FTP directory from Windows Explorer and everything works fine, except I can't open files directly. If I double click on a picture, it opens in Firefox. The same goes for videos and music, but they won't play at all. Is there a way to open files like they are on my local disk?

Comment: Same behaviour with the ftp being hosted on a Windows machine (actually Windows Server) and accessing from a windows 10 Client. Actually it opens in the default browser.